# How to seperate UI-thread from Main-thread

Tags: node.js, electron

Is it possible to separate `UI-thread` from `Main-thread` while using `Electron`?

I'm currently using child_process's to separate the heavier code from `Main/UI-thread`, but the `UI` still stops working until the child_process's are finished.

What can I do about this? or have I been doing it all wrong?

Comment: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes

Comment: @Styx So if I move the "heavy" part to the main-thread(main.js) it shouldn't stop the UI? I just tried that, and it still stops the UI until it's done.

Comment: "Main thread" and "UI thread" is the same thing. If you want to do heavy tasks you should move them to separate processes (workers).

Comment: Can you show a minimum example? Are you using `remote` ?
Regarding "doing it all wrong", I've found this talk https://www.infoq.com/presentations/electron-pitfalls/ very useful, in particular the bit in the middle about the problem electron-remote is solving.